# Fitting distribution in Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normal-distribution

I am trying to fit my data to the distributions in the following code with Scipy, like this:

```py
import scipy.stats

# data is read from a file
parameters = {}
dist_names = ['lognorm',
              'norm',
              'pearson3',
              'gumbel_r',
              'weibull_min', 
              'weibull_max']

for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(data)
    parameters[dist_name] = param
print( parameters['norm'] )
```

After I running the code, I look up for the parameters of loc and scale in each distribution and they are different from other programmas I have used. For example with the normal distribution the scale parameter corresponds to the **Biased** standard deviation and I am not able to change it with a ddof parameter. Please, What am I missing?

Comment: first you should show result which you get and result which you expect. You could also add what other programs you used.

Comment: you should get back the biased estimator. i don't know what is the issue you have here.